# How to prepare input data for multiple sequences LSTM in Keras?

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I have 5000 videos of 10 seconds each. For each video I extracted 300 frames (30 fps) and, for each frame, I extracted 50 features. So, my dataset can be represented as a cube with dimensions (frames=300, features=50, videos=5000)

I want to create a stateful LSTM in Keras but I can't understand how can I shape my input and what is the best way to train my model?

After reading several articles, I thought one possible solution:

1. Create subsequences from each sequence. For example, if window_size = 30, I have 300 - 30 + 1 = 271 subsequences. Each subsequence has 50 features, so I have a cube with dimensions 271x30x50. I repeat this step for each of 5000 samples.
2. Train the model giving in input one cube at time, so my Python code should be something like this:

   ```
   for e in epochs:

       for x in cubes:

           mdoel.fit(x, y, shuffle=False, batch_size=30, epochs=1)

           model.reset_states()
   ```

Is my solution correct? If yes, are there better ways to perform this task?
What about the batch_size=30? Is it correct or the batch_size has to perfectly divide the number of subsequences?

Comment: I guess for an LSTM your input should have a shape like (videos=5000, frames=300, features=50).

Comment: In this article http://philipperemy.github.io/keras-stateful-lstm/ he creates subsequences for each sequence. Is it useless?

Comment: If i am not wrong this article is referring to dataset needs where a look back is needed like stock market data. Can you give an idea of what your current task is about like classification or labeling ... . I am just trying to figure out is the sub sampling necessary in your use-case.

Comment: Sure, sorry for the incomplete description. From each frame of the videos I extract the points (x,y) of the head of the person. I want to use the LSTM to predict the engagement of the person, so I thought to use the window_size for this task and create subsequences

Comment: So are these 5000 videos of 10 sec duration mutually exclusive or chopped parts of video. By mutually exclusive i mean each 10 sec video has a corresponding output in your training set.

Comment: they are mutually exclusive and I have a label assigned for each of 10 seconds video

Comment: So here is my take, since all the data that a network needs to find a pattern or make a decision is present in a single record/sample I would not consider sub sampling each video like in this case. You can consider using stateless LSTM with an input shape(5000, 300, 50) directly.

Comment: Thanks for your suggest, i will try this method. What about the batch size? In stateless after every batch the state is reset. I could set a batch size = 300 but I don't think is the correct way